# Error in x$Version : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

I tried to run the occupancy model, and kept getting error message`Error in x$Version : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. I have checked the variable `visitData` and it is not atomic vector. I am so confused.

```
library(R2jags)
library(sparta) 
out <- occDetFunc(taxa_name = "Aleurodiscus disciformis",
                  occDetdata = visitData$occDetdata,
                  spp_vis = visitData$spp_vis,
                  n_iterations = 50,
                  nyr = 2,
                  burnin =15 ,
                  thinning = 3,
                  n_chains = 3,
                  write_results = TRUE,
                  modeltype = c("ranwalk", "halfcauchy", "catlistlength"),
                  return_data = TRUE)
```

```
> str(visitData)
List of 2
 $ spp_vis   :'data.frame': 37558 obs. of  199 variables:
  ..$ visit                       : chr [1:37558] "02013-05-211" "MF792009-03-151" "MF792013-04-211" "MF792017-12-231" ...
  ..$ Abortiporus biennis         : logi [1:37558] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
  ..$ Aleurodiscus disciformis    : logi [1:37558] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 .. [list output truncated]
```

```
$ occDetdata:'data.frame':  37558 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ visit: chr [1:37558] "02013-05-211" "MF792009-03-151" "MF792013-04-211" "MF792017-12-231" ...
  ..$ site : chr [1:37558] "0" "MF79" "MF79" "MF79" ...
  ..$ L    : int [1:37558] 1 1 2 4 1 7 1 1 1 2 ...
  ..$ TP   : num [1:37558] 2013 2009 2013 2017 2019 ...
```

Comment: The error message can often occur when you try to use '$' on objects without named components (such as data frames or lists), e.g. `1$version` throws the same error message. It could be that what you think is a data frame is getting converted to something else.